# Securing my web service with apache ubuntu

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

Here is my actual [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061712/change-www-directory-mode-only-from-web-application/1061716). In that question, Mr. Rinzwind guided me. I did the following as per the guide.

1. Creating Dedicated User and Group.

```
$ sudo groupadd apache
$ sudo useradd apache -g apache -d /dev/null/ -s /sbin/nologin
```

2. Modified Apache Configuration as below.

```
$ sudo cp /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.bak
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    User apache
    Group apache
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

3. make "data" be owned by the "CGI app user" and set it to "700" for directories and "600" for files.

```
$ sudo adduser serverdata
$ sudo usermod -a -G apache serverdata 
$ sudo chown -R serverdata:apache /var/myproj/data/
$ sudo find /var/myproj/data/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
$ sudo find /var/myproj/data/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```

4. Added 'www' ownership to group.

```
$ sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/myproj/www/
$ sudo chmod -R 775 /var/myproj/www/
```

After this, I wrote a `cgi` call to copy a file from `/var/myproj/data/` to `/var/myproj/www/`. But It didn't work.

What I missed in this settings? Why It couldn't get copy of that file from my `Data` directory to `www` directory which are all in the same group `apache`.

`Test.cgi` located in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` just read this file '`/var/myproj/data/test.html`' and copies into '`/var/myproj/www/`'. But that `Test.cgi` doesn't read anything from '`/var/myproj/data/`' location.

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: I think my data directory files couldn't be read by my cgi application.